# Best approach for security in WCF - and certificate error

Tags: wcf, security, certificate

Here's the scenario. We're providing software via a web interface, all hosted by us. However, the service does need to communicate a bit with our customer, so we're planning to install a WCF service on their site which can talk back to our service.

Part of the job of this service will be to authenticate users against Active Directory, which means sending usernames and passwords over the wire. These need to be secured. The original plan was simply to encrypt them but then I arrived on the project and was aware that WCF services can be certificate secured.

However, we don't really want to have to purchase and install a properly signed certificate for every local installation. That means using makecert.exe certificates which in turns means turning off a lot of security checks. At this point I'm at the limit of my expertise when it comes to security - is it a bad idea to try using unsigned certificates in production environments? If so, in what manner is it insecure?

I've hit a snag getting the service running locally with a certificate in any case, and if anyone could help it'd be appreciated. The service runs fine without the certificate, so the problem clearly isn't there. When I try and start the service, I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials.
```

So that appears to mean it can't find the certificate. But it can: because if I change the find terms I get a different message saying the certificate I'm after isn't in the store. Here's the relevant bits of config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Namespace.Endpoint"
               behaviorConfiguration="default">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/Endpoint"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureWsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Namespace.IContract" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureWsHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication 
                 certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"
                  revocationMode="NoCheck" />
              <certificate storeName="My" 
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" 
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            findValue="MyTestCert" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The certificate and private key are both accessible by the user that the service is running under. So why can't it use the certificate as installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message `The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials` states, you need to provide a service cert. HTTPS involves the server cert and an optional client cert.

```
<serviceCredentials>
    <serviceCertificate findValue="MyTestServerCert"
           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
               storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
</serviceCredentials>
```

As far as using self-signed certificates, it is okay to use if you have control over the machines where the cert will be used. If you use a root CA to sign your certs and can add this root CA to the list of trusted CAs in a machine, you don't have to relax the cert checks. Why do people pay money to get certs then? Answer is you will not have this control over all the machines. In a public facing site, you cannot ask all your visitors to add your root CA to the trusted CA list. You want some one every body trusts to issue your cert and that is where CA comes in.

BTW, if you plan to issue a cert for every user, it will be a big hassle and admin overhead to manage all the certs.